# Visual Studio 2005 Open Project Dialog Slow as Molasses

Tags: performance, freeze, visual-studio-2005

Whenever I try to open a project in Visual Studio 2005 (Windows XP), my open project dialog become slow as molasses - navigating down one level of folders typically takes almost 60 seconds. Finding the project and opening it can take up 4-5 minutes, which is just ridiculous.

I've checked the open project dialogs of other programs - only VS2005 is acting this way. What could be causing this problem and how do I go about solving it (apart from reinstalling VS2005 / windows)

(Edit: Even VS2008 on the same machine does not have this problem. I don't know what's wrong.)

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any remote project hosted somewhere, or does any of your "solutions" involve fetching source or syncing with a remote version control? Perhaps vs2005 doesn't handle unreliable network connections.

other hint: what is vs doing while you browse? have you tried setting all options to default?

Comment: It's all on local disk. Even if it is, then VS2008 should be affected too. Compiling and all are fine. It's just anything that involves opening a open file dialog that is slow as molasses. It looks like it's trying to do something, but it's really really slow. Not much signs of disk activity however.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Whenever I opened up one of my VS 2005 project, the controls inside the pages took ages to load.  But I finally managed to solve the problem.  It turned out my pages had references to a third party component which I no longer used in the project.

When I deleted the references, the VS loads in seconds.

Comment: what do you mean by Pages?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) when you open the Open File dialog.  Make sure you set the filter to just log events for Visual Studio.  This should show you exactly what Visual Studio is doing.  It is likely that it is hitting the disk a lot or trying to access a network share somewhere that is not available, but this tool should tell you exactly what its doing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a network drive mapped to a server that your machine can no longer see
check out all your mapped network drives that you can open them, and disconnect any that you cant access